# JSTL tag <c:param name="pivotId" value="${param.pivotId}" /> doesn't evaluate in pentaho 7.1

Tags: java, jstl, pentaho

I have an issue with the evaluation of `${varName}` in JSTL tags in pentaho 7.1

This is the jsp:

```
 <c:url value="../STPivot" var="mdxURL">
    <c:param name="pivotId" value="${param.pivotId}" />
    <c:param name="pivotPart" value="mdx" />
 </c:url>
 <%
  System.out.println("mdxUrl ->" + pageContext.findAttribute("mdxURL"));
 %>
```

And this the output of println in pentaho 6.1 and 7.1:

6.1
`../STPivot?pivotId=95d6c6e6-6ba1-4e07-94a9-9ea1c2721974&pivotPart=mdx`

7.1
`../STPivot?pivotId=%24%7Bparam.pivotId%7D&pivotPart=mdx`

As you can see there is not evaluation for `${param.pivotId}` in pentaho 7.1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set the attribute `isELIgnored` to `false`...

```
<%@ page session="true" contentType="text/html;" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

...and change the uri of `c` tag to...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Instead of `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core`